# Bootstrap 4 link right float

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Is there a better way to get the link to the right side without having to place it in 'clearfix' div?

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <a href="/posts/create" class="btn btn-info mb-1 float-right">+ New Post</a>
</div>
```

Comment: We need the parent div. But basically, just add the `text-right` class to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-right` class in parent `div` , or you can use flex also.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
 <a href="/posts/create" class="btn btn-info mb-1">+ New Post</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   
    <a style='float:right;' href="/posts/create" class="btn btn-info mb-1 float-right">+ New Post</a>
```